# PyArrow installation for Xbbg doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, pip, bloomberg, pyarrow

I'm trying to set up a data pipeline between Bloomberg and Python. I have a Bloomberg terminal, a Windows 64-bit machine, Python 3.7.4 and a Sublime Text environment up and working. My goal is to install the XBBG package: https://pypi.org/project/xbbg/.

I've followed the steps on https://pypi.org/project/xbbg/ and I have installed:

- Bloomberg C++ SDK version 3.12.1 or higher
- Bloomberg Open API (need to install manually as shown below)
- pdblp - pandas wrapper for Bloomberg Open API
- numpy, pandas, ruamel.yaml

However the `pip install pyarrow` installation does not work (see traceback below), even when I tried earlier versions of `pyarrow`.

```py
pip install pyarrow
Collecting pyarrow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/75/e87ad78b3a0d1250984331e59648fac43218f00599fd570318447178c650/pyarrow-0.14.0.tar.gz (436kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 440kB 1.8MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r81qamg4\pyarrow\setup.py", line 29, in <module>
        from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r81qamg4\pyarrow\
```

```py
So I installed Cython:

pip install Cython
Collecting Cython
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/95/d0b8d1b15ddb1129b841b1c537e935dce19ae4ccf7da65ade0b37e210434/Cython-0.29.12-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (1.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 2.1MB/s
Installing collected packages: Cython
Successfully installed Cython-0.29.12
```

and tried installing PyArrow again:

```py
pip install pyarrow
Collecting pyarrow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/75/e87ad78b3a0d1250984331e59648fac43218f00599fd570318447178c650/pyarrow-0.14.0.tar.gz
Collecting numpy>=1.14 (from pyarrow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/46/656c25b39fc152ea525eef14b641993624a6325a8ae815b200de57cff0bc/numpy-1.16.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (10.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.0MB 1.3MB/s
Collecting six>=1.0.0 (from pyarrow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, six, pyarrow
  Running setup.py install for pyarrow ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\users\alain tchibozo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gfndyai5\\pyarrow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xs9wfdwm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-gfndyai5\pyarrow\.eggs\setuptools_scm-3.3.3-py3.7.egg\setuptools_scm\utils.py:119: UserWarning: 'git' was not found
      warnings.warn("%r was not found" % name)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\csv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\cuda.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\feather.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\filesystem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\flight.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\hdfs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\ipc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\jvm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\orc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\pandas_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\parquet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\plasma.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\serialization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_generated_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\deserialize_buffer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\pandas_examples.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\strategies.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_array.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_compute.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_convert_builtin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_csv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_cuda.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_cuda_numba_interop.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_cython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_deprecations.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_extension_type.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_feather.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_filesystem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_flight.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_gandiva.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_hdfs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_io.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_ipc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_jvm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_memory.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_orc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_pandas.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_parquet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_plasma.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_plasma_tf_op.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_scalars.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_schema.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_strategies.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_table.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_tensor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\test_types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    copying pyarrow\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    running egg_info
    writing pyarrow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pyarrow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to pyarrow.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to pyarrow.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pyarrow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.asv'
    writing manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying pyarrow\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_csv.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_cuda.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_cuda.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_flight.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_json.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_orc.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_orc.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_parquet.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_parquet.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\_plasma.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\array.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\benchmark.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\builder.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\error.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\feather.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\gandiva.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\io-hdfs.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\io.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\ipc.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\lib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\lib.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\memory.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\pandas-shim.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\public-api.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\scalar.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\serialization.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\table.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    copying pyarrow\types.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\includes
    copying pyarrow\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\includes
    copying pyarrow\includes\common.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\includes
    copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\includes
    copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_cuda.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\includes
    copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_flight.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\includes
    copying pyarrow\includes\libgandiva.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tensorflow
    copying pyarrow\tensorflow\plasma_op.cc -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tensorflow
    copying pyarrow\tests\pyarrow_cython_example.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\README.md -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.emptyFile.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.emptyFile.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.test1.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.test1.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.testDate1900.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.testDate1900.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
    copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.7\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
    running build_ext
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gfndyai5\pyarrow\setup.py", line 606, in <module>
        url='https://arrow.apache.org/'
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\alain\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gfndyai5\pyarrow\setup.py", line 94, in run
        self._run_cmake()
      File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gfndyai5\pyarrow\setup.py", line 273, in _run_cmake
        raise RuntimeError('Not supported on 32-bit Windows')
    RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gfndyai5\\pyarrow\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xs9wfdwm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gfndyai5\pyarrow\
```

I've tried to read up this issue and it appears to me that either:

1. pyarrow is not compatible with python3.7 (which is strange because I've tried installation on an OS machine)
2. I'm doing the installation wrong.

   > If 1) I'm more than happy to downgrade my python version. If you know what python version (more than 3) supports pyarrow I'll be happy to downgrade it.
   >   If 2) Please provide indications to how properly install it.
3. (Unlikely) If there is a way to install xbbg without pyarrow, I'll be happy to know how. Remember the goal is to install xbbg.

Many thanks.

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html the official pages states that PyArrow is compatible with python3.7: ''PyArrow pledges to maintain compatibility with Python 2.7 until the end of 2019. Other than that, PyArrow is currently compatible with Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7.'', ''PyArrow is regularly built and tested on Windows, macOS and various Linux distributions (including Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04). We strongly recommend using a 64-bit system.''

Comment: ''If you encounter any importing issues of the pip wheels on Windows, you may need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.'' I've also completed these steps and I get the same error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyarrow` [requires 64-bit Python](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/bc837e64f5a2b6bf3d9cebe69c491600f645a8c8/python/setup.py#L271). Verify that you have [64-bit Python](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/bc837e64f5a2b6bf3d9cebe69c491600f645a8c8/python/setup.py#L43):

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)"
python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
```

Comment: Spot on. I have python 32 bit so I'm going to get the 64-bit version and try that.

Comment: Spot on. I was using a 32-bit version. It works now with the 64-bit version. Excellent, many thanks!